# Want to bullet proof while loop with try-catch

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I have this hw problem - Write a program that reads a number and prints all of its binary digits: Print the remainder number % 2, then replace the number with number / 2. Keep going until the number is 0.
It successfully displays the binary digits, but I want to bullet proof it so that it won't crash when letters are used. It doesn't crash but I want to allow the user to enter another number without restarting the program. Any tips on how I can do this?

```
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = 0;
    System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
    try {
        number = scanIn.nextInt();
   } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println("Please only enter integers!");
        number = 0;    
        scanIn.nextLine();
   }            
    while (number > 0) {
        System.out.println(number % 2);
        number /= 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `scanner.hasNextInt()` ?

Comment: I think you can still benefit from that. You just need to wrap the part where you obtain input in a while loop which exits once you've got input you can use

Comment: If you correctly use `hasNextInt()`, like @Harvtronix suggested, you will not need to catch exception, because `InputMismatchException` will never be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 loops, 
The first one will take an input until it is an integer (Integer.parseInt()) Surrounded by a try/catch

Then when you have confirmed an input that is an integer you begin your loop.

Comment: `Integer.tryParse()`?

Comment: Sorry - early in the morning, Its   Integer parseInt(String s)  but surrounded by a TryCatch.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to surround your code in another while loop that iterates forever and breaks out of the loop when a certain condition is met. I also modified your code to repeatedly prompt for an integer if invalid input is entered.

```
Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = 0;

while(true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter an integer, or 0 to quit: ");

    // input verification 
    boolean valid = false;
    while(!valid) {
        try {
            number = scanIn.nextInt();
            valid = true;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.out.println("Please only enter integers!");
            System.out.print("Please enter an integer, or 0 to quit: ");
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    // break out of the loop if 0 is entered
    if(number == 0) {
        break;
    }

    while (number > 0) {
        System.out.println(number % 2);
        number /= 2;
    }
}
```